# How to use LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> word = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();`
And i have List for files:`static List<string> file = new List<string>(60);`

Before, I used to use this path to write file information
string line;

```
string[] lines;
        string[] linesUnos;
        string[] sp = { " " };
        int i = (int)obj;
        StreamReader reder = new StreamReader(file[i]);
        line = " ";
    while (!reder.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = reder.ReadLine().ToLower();
        lines = line.Split(sp, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var w in lines )
        {
            word.AddOrUpdate(w, 1, (key, oldValue) => oldValue + 1);
        }
    }
```

In this case the right to use a LINQ?
I try this way,but it't not right:

```
IEnumerable<string> f, w;

line = reder.ReadLine().ToLower();

f = from lin in line.Split(sp, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) select lin;

word = line.ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Count());
```

Comment: Please add your data sample and expected result.

Comment: I have data like that:"kbSFeJGHp gsoJhUO Avjpn1zhMhVQXBjhJ elGYgYhTVdmqfS iXrgEvHP lCKUXPRKOXkFFXo RtybwtWmRGqNUF vGNcp1dnnbsclqq fAnlIBNftk wqpTnGcY 
esqxDpXkDfx JuhGXMfdBl dJAuSTKOvavpfgY 1JYYpxZH JKRoKshhCCMaKRdMwn wifbuobIYciflOfb RKaE1wnTTOufo iFlBcaQBHqDn cveZxrYWI 1uLSnaWnjH 
VXtPyXEjOq AktxrYaiUwxwjHjkAKQ 1VoyKJqJGHcTh kGhQaoBp 1NuNjyNNGnwVuOvm MKPbpvCS EpmEztkmjBaiVMAkDX atGYOxkWerzz1FkCj VminmdjMUOmsajEytuj lGBPuEpUOKBvZ " and i need data like : word:kbSFeJGHp  count:1

Comment: Your code makes no sense: why create `lines` and then never use it? Before posting, create a working and compiling sample. Copy/Paste it.

Comment: oh,yes.I make an mistakes and didn't change it. i use foreach (var w in lines)

Comment: Use the [edit] button. You may want to fix the indentation while you're there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try doing some *reverse engineering*. It seems, that you have several files (in the `file` list) organized like this:

```
 some words
 several new words
 nothing new
```

and you want some kind of a *dictionary* as a result

```
{"some", 1}     // 1: "some' appears just once
{"words", 2}    // 2: 'words' appears twice
{"several", 1}
{"new", 2} 
{"nothing", 1}
...
```

where `Key` is a word itself, and `Value` is its frequency. If it's your case and if you want to implement it with a help of *Linq* while using *parallel processes*, try using *PLinq*; something like this:

```
  Dictionary<string, int> dict = file
    .AsParallel()                              // Doing in parallel
    .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(files)) // Read all lines of all files
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(            // Split each line into words
       new char[] {' '}, 
       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   // You may want to process words here, e.g. get rid of "stop words"
    .GroupBy(w => w) // Group by each word
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.Count());
```

Please, notice that you'll get just `Dictionary`, not `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: What is the `files` variable?

Comment: No `files` variable should be there according the question but `file` list. I'm sorry for the typo if I have made any